# how to write this query using hql

Tags: mysql, hibernate, hql

Thi is my query:

```
SELECT d.fullName,d.doctorId,d.speciality, t.hospital, t.date, t.time
FROM Doctor d, TimeTable t
WHERE d.doctorId = t.doctorId and d.fullName = 'Subash Nisam' and t.date = '2017.03.02' 
ORDER BY t.date;
```

I've two tables->Doctor and TimeTable

```
@Entity
public class TimeTable {

private int timeTableId;
private String time;
private String date;
private String hospital;

private Doctor doctor;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = AUTO)
public int getTimeTableId() {
    return timeTableId;
}

public void setTimeTableId(int timeTableId) {
    this.timeTableId = timeTableId;
}

public String getTime() {
    return time;
}

public void setTime(String time) {
    this.time = time;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public String getHospital() {
    return hospital;
}

public void setHospital(String hospital) {
    this.hospital = hospital;
}

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "doctorId", nullable = false)
public Doctor getDoctor() {
    return doctor;
}

public void setDoctor(Doctor doctor) {
    this.doctor = doctor;
}

}
//////////////////////////////////////////

@Entity
public class Doctor {

private int doctorId;
private String fullName;
private String regNo;
private String designation;
private String speciality;
private String address;
private String contactNo;
private String email;
private String workingTime;
private String password;
private String branch;

---------------------------------------------
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = AUTO)
public int getDoctorId() {
    return doctorId;
}
```

---

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "doctor")
public Set<TimeTable> getTimeTables() {
    return timeTables;
}

public void setTimeTables(Set<TimeTable> timeTables) {
    this.timeTables = timeTables;
}
}
```

I want to write my query using hql. hope your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this syntax:

```
select d.fullName, d.doctorId, d.speciality, t.hospital, t.date, t.time
from Doctor as d
inner join d.timeTables t
where d.fullName = 'Subash Nisam' and t.date = '2017-03-02'
```

Comment: when I try this query generated a query in server output.

Comment: ...and what is the output?

Comment: It is too long for a comment. I've submitted it as a post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
select Doctor.fullname, Doctor.doctorId, Doctor.speciality, TimeTable.hospital, TimeTable.date, TimeTable.time from  Doctor inner join TimeTable  on Doctor.doctorId  =TimeTable.doctorId  where Doctor.fullname='Subash' and Timetable.date='2017-03-02' order by Timetable.date;
```

Answer (score 0):

@Tim Biegeleisen------->
 Here is the output

```
select
    doctor0_.doctorId as doctorId1_3_0_,
    timetables1_.timeTableId as timeTabl1_5_1_,
    doctor0_.address as address2_3_0_,
    doctor0_.branch as branch3_3_0_,
    doctor0_.contactNo as contactN4_3_0_,
    doctor0_.designation as designat5_3_0_,
    doctor0_.email as email6_3_0_,
    doctor0_.fullName as fullName7_3_0_,
    doctor0_.password as password8_3_0_,
    doctor0_.regNo as regNo9_3_0_,
    doctor0_.speciality as special10_3_0_,
    doctor0_.workingTime as working11_3_0_,
    timetables1_.date as date2_5_1_,
    timetables1_.doctorId as doctorId5_5_1_,
    timetables1_.hospital as hospital3_5_1_,
    timetables1_.time as time4_5_1_ 
from
    Doctor doctor0_ 
inner join
    TimeTable timetables1_ 
        on doctor0_.doctorId=timetables1_.doctorId 
where
    doctor0_.fullName='Subash Nisam' 
    and timetables1_.date='2017.03.02'
```

It gives all result of the doctor such as fullname, password, address...
but I want to get fullName and doctorId from doctor table and other data from timetable table.

Comment: Hibernate returns _objects_, not records.  Nevertheless, I think you can specify which fields you want to select, q.v. my updated answer.